# $T$-invariance of $U$ is equivalent to $T^{*}$-invariance of $U^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

Is the Following argument correct?

Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Prove that $U$ is invariant under $T$ if and only if $U^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T^*$.

*Proof.* Given that $U$ is invariant under $T$ then $\langle w,Tu\rangle = 0,\forall (u,w)\in U\times U^{\perp}$ equivalently $\langle w,(T^*)^*u\rangle = 0 ,\forall (u,w)\in U\times U^{\perp}$ this when taken together with the definition of the adjoint of $T$ is equivalent to $\langle T^*w,u\rangle =  0,\forall (u,w)\in U\times U^{\perp}$ thus $U^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T^{*}$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: It is okay. Just make sure that you know how $\langle T^*w,v\rangle=0$ for all $(u,w)\in U\times U^{\bot}$ implies that $U^{\bot}$ is $T^*$ invariant. One point that needs to be clear is that $U$ should be a closed subspace to get the "if" part, but maybe your definition of "subspace" already assumes closed.